# Google Calendar API v3 batch update in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, batching

I'm having trouble using the new Google Calendar API v3 python library. The documentation seems a bit sparse. I can authenticate and get events on a specific calendar. However, I would like to perform batch update as was possible with the gdata library:

```
# example from gdata
# feed that holds all the batch rquest entries
  request_feed = gdata.calendar.data.CalendarEventFeed()
# add the update entries to the batch feed
  request_feed.AddUpdate(entry=updateEntry1)
  request_feed.AddUpdate(entry=updateEntry2)
# submit the batch request to the server
  response_feed = self.cal_client.ExecuteBatch(request_feed, gdata.calendar.client.DEFAULT_BATCH_URL)
```

There is an example here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch#example in html. But can I do it using the python library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's generic Google API Python library batch instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch). Try something like:

```
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

def insert_event(request_id, response, exception):
  if exception is not None:
    # Do something with the exception
     pass
  else:
    # Do something with the response
    pass

service = build('calendar', 'v3')

batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=insert_event)

batch.add(service.events().quickAdd(calendarId="you@domain.com",
  text="Lunch with Jim on Friday"))
batch.add(service.events().quickAdd(calendarId="you@domain.com",
  text="Dinner with Amy on Saturday"))
batch.add(service.events().quickAdd(calendarId="you@domain.com",
  text="Breakfast with John on Sunday"))
batch.execute(http=http)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like just the thing.

Comment: @JayLee can you please let me know how can I render whole response to HTML from the batch request.... I am dealing with gmail api and I am getting response in insert_event function but I am not able to render it....

Comment: What's `http`? The name is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using the new_batch_http_request method in the Calendar API:

```
event = {
        'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
        'description': 'A chance to hear more about google.',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2021-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2021-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
}

event2 = {
        'summary': 'Rocky Balboa',
        'description': 'more products.',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2021-05-22T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2021-05-22T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },

}

from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
import httplib2
from googleapiclient import discovery



batch = service_calendar.new_batch_http_request()
batch.add(service_calendar.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=event2))
batch.add(service_calendar.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=event))
batch.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
batch = service.new_batch_http_request()
for event_id in list_of_events:
    batch.add(service.events().delete(eventId=event_id, calendarId=calendar_id), callback=callback)
    batch.add(service.events().insert(body=api_format, calendarId=calendar_id))

batch.execute()
```

Here's the complete code to create the service:

```
import os
import pickle
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from pathlib import Path

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

def authorize(json_path='credentials_oauth2.json', token_path='token.pickle', scopes=SCOPES):
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(token_path):
        with open(token_path, 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                json_path, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(token_path, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds


    def get_calendar_service(json_path, token_path):
        creds = authorize(json_path, token_path)
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
        return service
    
JSON_PATH = Path(r"../credentials/credentials.json")
TOKEN_PATH = Path(r"../credentials/token.pickle")

service = get_calendar_service(JSON_PATH, TOKEN_PATH)
```